# docker-ce: proxy password stopped working after upgrade

Tags: dns, proxy, docker, ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and my proxy configuration worked fine with this version:

```
> docker --version
Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6
```

I recently did and `apt-get upgrade` and it pulled a new version of docker-ce:

```
> docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

Now I get failures of the form:

```
> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on 10.198.0.199:53: no such host.
```

(10.198.0.199 is our company's internal DNS server)

Here are my contents of my `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/10_docker_proxy.conf`

```
[Service]
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
```

I tried single and double quoting the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables:

```
Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091"
Environment="HTTPS_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091"
```

and

```
Environment='HTTP_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091'
Environment='HTTPS_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091'
```

with the same error.

It looks like is related to the `DOMAIN\\` part of the username, because if I do this (i.e. don't supply a password):

```
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://DOMAIN\\username@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http:/DOMAIN\\username@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
```

I get the same `proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on 10.198.0.199:53: no such host` error,
but if I leave off the DOMAIN:

```
Environment=HTTP_PROXY=http://username@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=http:/username@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
```

I get

```
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: authenticationrequired.
```

Something needs to be tweaked with the URL parsing library?

In the mean time I will be reverting to a working docker:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=17.12.0~ce-0~ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the "\" character.  This works:

`Environment=HTTP_PROXY=H://DOMAIN%5cusername:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091
Environment=HTTPS_PROXY=H://DOMAIN%5cusername:password@proxy.xyzcompany.com:9091`

Comment: Where "H" is "http", the markup wouldn't let me enter this for some-reason.

Comment: Looks like things broke again when we upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04 with docker 18.05.  The solution was to escape each % with %% ...